# Understanding andThen() function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Consider the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<String, Integer> f1 = str ->  str.length();
    f1.andThen(i -> {
        System.out.println("length is " + i);
        return "why do I need to return a String here?";
    }).apply("12345");
}
```

I'm trying to understand why do I have to return `String`.

What's the logic behind that? I'd expect that `andThen` would accept a `Consumer<Integer>` let's say or something similar.

So why do `andThen()` requires me to return the type of the original input?

Comment: Because the parameter is not of type `Consumer` but `Function`. See [`Function#andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Take a string to get its length `andThen` do some transformation on the String using its length and return it.

Comment: `Function<String, Integer> length = str ->  str.length(); Function<Integer, String> hex = val -> Integer.toHexString(val); Function<String,String> lengthInHex = length.andThen(hex);`  Is that incomprehensible? Alternatively: `Function<String, Integer> length = String::length; Function<String,String> lengthInHex = length.andThen(Integer::toHexString);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can be achieved via

```
Function<String, Integer> f1 = str ->  str.length();
Consumer<Integer> printer = i -> System.out.println("length is " + i);
printer.accept(f1.apply("12345"));
```

`andThen` is for chaining functions together. Functions always have results.